# Typescript compiling vendor, exclude wont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, typescript, webpack

I started trying TypeScript but I got a little weird issue.

I first started trying with a fresh Laravel installation and made some changes to start writing TypeScript. Everything compiled fine and I loved it.

Now I am trying to implement it in my hobby project but I got a weird issue.

I get this error when I try to compile: (and many more in vendor)
`ERROR in /someLongStuff/vendor/symfony/translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts`

It is failing cause it is trying to compile something from Symfony. This is weird cause my fresh installation should have the same issue, but it doesn't.

This is my webpack.mix.js file

```
// TYPESCRIPT
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                    exclude: [
                        /node_modules/,
                        /vendor/ <-- try to exclude vendor
                    ]
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"]
        }
    })
```

And this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    }
}
```

Any one?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I did, it did not work. My collega got it to work some days later. We did compare our work, and yes there were some differents but we still dont know what the issue really is.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly excluding `vendor` in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
]
```